# Как обновить список после удаления?

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular8, angular10

У меня есть список пользователей и каждый раз после нажатия на кнопку удалить ,хочу что бы список обновлялся.Вот так выглядит мой список, при нажатии на хрестик пользователь удаляется , и при этом я все равно остаюсь на странице списка пользователей. Хочу когда нажал на кнопку удалить список обновился и уже не показывал пользователя которого я удалил. Когда я нажимаю удалить и перезагружаю страницу, то все работает отлично. Я не знаю может можно как то просто перезагрузить страничку в effect
[image]

Мой effect на удаление

```
 @Effect()
    DeleteUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<deleteUserAction.DeleteUser>(deleteUserAction.EDeleteUser.DeleteUser),
        map((action: deleteUserAction.DeleteUser) => action.payload),
        mergeMap((id: number) =>
            this.adminService.deleteUser(id).pipe(
                map(() =>
                {
                    console.log(id);
                    return new deleteUserAction.DeleteUserSuccess(id);
                }),
                catchError((errorMessage) => {
                    console.log(errorMessage);

                    let error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`${errorMessage.error.text}`));
                    console.log(error);
                    return of(new BaseError(error));
                })
            ))
    );
```

Пробовал сделать вот так , типа когда удаление успешно перейти обратно на эту же страницу , но это неработает

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
    DeleteUserSuccess: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<deleteUserAction.DeleteUserSuccess>(deleteUserAction.EDeleteUser.DeleteUserSuccess),
        tap(() => {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin/list-client');
        })
    )
```

Диспатчу так

```
 deleteUser(id){
    console.log(id);
    this.store$.dispatch(new DeleteUser(id));
  }
```

Comment: что делает `DeleteUserSuccess` метод

Comment: @Ashot Aleqsanyan  Он принимает id юзера которого я удалил, а effect DeleteUserSuccess по сути ничего, я просто думал что если буду возвращать роут списка, то смогу перезагрузить всю страницу. Но не тут то было)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дмитрий посмотрите в `DeleteUserSuccess` вам нужно модифицировать состояние вашего массива в App Store.
Bам нужно добавить логику для этого.

```
const yourReducer = createReducer(
  initialState, // initial state of your state
  on(deleteUserAction.DeleteUserSuccess, (state, {id} => ({ ...state, users: (id) => state.users.filter(user => iser.id !== payload)  })),

);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return yourReducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))

Comment: @Dmitriy нет проблем, рад помочь.